# Java annotation fields setter and getter how to

Tags: java, android, annotations

What I want to accomplish but don't understand really how it works its

```
@Table(name = "Categories")
public class Category extends Model { 
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
}
```

With this code I want to annotation generate their respective setter and getter so I can use like

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setName("My Name");
category.save();
```

Whey I need setter and getter and not access/edit the value directly? Because some values has different treatment, like relations, and because I want to have fields that don't want to be edited. And I'm too lazy to do manually all the time this, with every model, also save a lot of work later to just put an annotation and set their field

My inspiration to try this was [Android Annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) seems a solid and cool library, I know maybe its too advanced but my goal with this experiment its to have a library like that but focused on models like active record or another orm.

Tuts, tips, advices, books are welcome.

Regards

**Edit 2013-10-25**

My goal is to build a library capable to do this, because I'm too curious and want to learn how internally work, so I'll be able to power my framework with this feature, as jet just are small utilities but in the future I hope it save me a lot of work, you can see at github [WSD Android](https://github.com/norman784/wsd-android)

Comment: Asking for pointers to tutorials or books is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If possible, please rephrase your problem so that it's a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are too lazy to create the setters and getters of your variables why not just let your IDE generate it for you?

but if you do really insist, take a look at this [plugin](http://projectlombok.org/)

This simply allows you to do this

```
@Table(name = "Categories")
public class Category extends Model { 

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
}
```

WARNING.

the plugin is not well documented, you also need to configure your IDE to actually see it(eg `category.getName()`)

Comment: I'm lazy to do it all the time, but also need to be customizable, or in other words need to add some fields types that aren't strings, or numbers, etc. because i'm using a PaaS that their relation works in this way, model.getRelation('relationalField').add(relationObject); and I want to abstract it just as model.addRelationalField(relationObject) or model.removeRelationalField(relationObject). And last I want to learn how annotation works, so my frameworks can be powered with this feature. thanks... (i will update my question)

Comment: If I remember correctly lombok is open sourced, you can check their code out to see how they are doing it, then cater it to your needs. model.getRelation('relationalField').addField(relationObject). I can see that builder pattern or delegation will fit your needs.